# Why do I get an error if I didn't specify brackets in a function even if it's only one statement in C?

Tags: c, function, brackets

In for-loops, while-loops, and if-statements allow me to not specify the brackets if I put only statement in it like so:

```
for (fahr = LOWER; fahr <= UPPER; fahr = fahr + STEP)
    printf("%3d %6.1f\n", fahr, fahrToCelsius(fahr));
```

But if I do it in a function like so:

```
float fahrToCelsius(int fahr)
    return (5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32);
```

It gives me an error.

Why can't I omit brackets in functions with only one statement?

Comment: You can do it in just one line though `float fahrToCelsius(int fahr){ return (5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32);}` and if its a class function check out what `inline` is

Comment: Actually an interesting question. In the end it's just another scope (let's ignore the standards text wording), so why is it optional? Since I wouldn't expect any reasonings in the standards specification, I guess this is really up to interpretation and you won't get any specific answer other than "because its written there".

Comment: According to the answers I've read it seems it's because the standards say so... I think if I might be able to understand the answer once I get more experience in programming.

Comment: @Victor Asdasd although that's good but it's kinda` harder to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there is a `C` standards specification backing the language compiler and its implementation.

Breaking specifications(like writing non-standard code) is a bad idea in general and should be avoided to increase readability, maintainability and portability of your application.

Good compilers enforce standards based coding.

See here [Open C Standards](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, it's required by the language syntax.

The C language syntax says that a function-definition must end with a compound-statement, and a compound-statement must begin with `{` and end with `}`.

The syntax for for loops, while loops, and if statements must end with a "statement" syntax, which doesn't have to be a compound-statement (though it can be).

See the "Language syntax summary" in the C language standard (Annex A in C11).

Comment: For one reason, A function definition without brackets could be ambiguous when the line it contains is special. For example 'void foo();' could either be a function that does nothing or a forward definition of the function to be defined later. Therefore, a spec that allows this would be unwise because it would greatly complicate the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Well you cant because C standart says so, as other answers mentioned, but if you really don't like brackets, you can try with preprocessor.

```
#define fahrToCelsius(fahr) ((5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32))
```

Comment: That's kind of cool but I think I'll do that once I learn more about preprocessor directives.

Comment: @exilonblack Well I just offered this as a possibility, but preprocessor is not for such things, so you should better use function instead.

Comment: Well I might use it for one line math functions like square, cube, roots, etc... That's why I up-voted your answer.